# Broken Loop and dim LEDs

Tags: arduino-uno, digitalwrite

I want to make 2 LEDs blink back and forth continuously, but they only do so once, and the second one is very dim.

code:

```
int ledone = 12;
int ledtwo = 10;
int keepgoing = 1;

void setup() {
pinMode(ledone, OUTPUT);
pinMode(ledtwo, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
 while (keepgoing == 1) {
  digitalWrite(ledone, HIGH);
  delay(80);
  digitalWrite(ledone, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledtwo, HIGH);
  delay(80);
  digitalWrite(ledtwo, LOW);
  delay(500);
 }
}
```

I am using an Arduino Uno and one 220 ohm resistor for each LED.

Comment: i have corrected keepgoing == 1, instead of keepgoing = 1, please check now.

Comment: By "second one", do you mean one of the LEDs?  If so swap the leads to them and then report back if the same kind of dimness still occurs – maybe one of your LEDs is just dimmer than the other.  If the dimness swaps, then try changing `ledtwo = 10` to  `ledtwo = 9`, ie to some other pin, and rewire accordingly – maybe one of your IO pins has a problem or your wires are loose.  Also try changing those fairly-short 80-ms delays to perhaps twice or three times as long.

Comment: @goddland_16, as a condition for an `if`, `keepgoing = 1` will always evaluate as true,which will keep the `while` statement going.   `keepgoing == 1` also will evaluate as true, given that  `keepgoing`  was initialized to 1.

Comment: swapping fixed my brightness, but how do I make my loop keep repeating, it only executes once :(

Comment: @JamesWaldby-jwpat7, yes, it is. For this context I assumed he meant it as keepgoing == 1.

Comment: it now looks like this:  void loop() {

  while (keepgoing == 1) {
digitalWrite(ledone, HIGH);
delay(160);

Comment: it still does not run more than once.

Comment: NerdyDude101, is the following a correct description of what you see?  When you press reset, LED 1 comes on briefly and goes off.  LED 2 comes on briefly and not as bright and goes off.  Then both LEDs stay off until you press reset again.

Comment: yes that is what I see.

Comment: Ok, what happens if you delete `while (keepgoing == 1) {` and the matching closing `}` ?

Comment: it stays the same.

Comment: May be some hardware or wiring problem... I would next try things like the following:  (a) with both LEDs wired up, comment out the digitalWrite()'s for one LED at a time, and see if `loop()` works; (b) pull the wire to one LED at a time, and see if `loop()` works (ie take one LED out of circuit, run test, put the LED back in, take the other out, run test); (c) try higher-resistance resistors, in case something is wrong with the ones you have.   BTW, does the Blink example sketch, which uses built-in LED, work ok?  And did the 160-ms delays look twice as long as the 80's?

Comment: You don't need the while loop. loop() loops forever anyway.

Comment: Ok. This is really weird. My code looks like this:

Comment: void loop() {
 while (keepgoing == 1) {
  digitalWrite(ledone, HIGH);
  //digitalWrite(ledtwo, LOW);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(ledone, LOW);
  //digitalWrite(ledtwo, HIGH);
  delay(500);

Comment: (of course it has proper spacing)

Comment: but both LEDs blinked on and then off once?!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is, that your delays are just too short, so you see the blinking not as blinking, but as a dim lit led.

Maybe you can try the following code:

```
void loop() {
 while (keepgoing == 1) {
  digitalWrite(ledone, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(ledtwo, LOW);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(ledone, LOW);
  digitalWrite(ledtwo, HIGH);
  delay(500);
 } 
}
```

Is this working?

Comment: I tried this code and each LED only blinked once. This is really confusing!